# How to make a nodejs with socketio cluster?

Tags: node.js, sockets, cluster-computing, socket.io

I write a chat app with nodejs, express and socketio.
It support some chat in one room, and support multiple rooms,
And I hold the client data in memory, such as there is global 
variable **rooms**, and i store client data like this..

```
var rooms =  {
  "room1": [
         {username: "user1", socket: user1Socket}, 
         {username: "user2", socket: user2Socket}, 
  ],
  "room2": [
         {username: "user3", socket: user3Socket}, 
         {username: "user4", socket: user4Socket}, 
  ]
}
```

but there are multiple serverss in cluster, the client didn't know to connect to which server, because this is the job of the load equalizer,  then a problem occured,  the user1 and the user2 should be in same room, but they may be connect to different server..

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your servers with a RedisStore. Have a look here for more information: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#server

Comment: Thanks, I configure the server with a redis store, it's works nice!

Comment: and i had made a redis server cluster now, I can find the connection of redis server on redis.on('end')  event, but i want to switch store redis server connect to other one in cluster, how can I do?

Comment: Doing again `io.set('store', ...)` with another RedisStore instance doesn't work?
Otherwise the best is maybe to use your load balancer.